# Modifying reference member from const member function in C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I am working on const-correctness of my code and just wondered why this code compiles:

```
class X
{
    int x;
    int& y;
public:
    X(int& _y):y(_y)
    {
    }
void f(int& newY) const
    {
        //x = 3; would not work, that's fine
        y = newY; //does compile. Why?
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int i1=0, i2=0;
    X myX(i1);
    myX.f(i2);
...
}
```

As far as I understand, f() is changing the object myX, although it says to be const. How can I ensure my compiler complains when I do assign to y? (Visual C++ 2008)

Thank a lot!

Comment: Imagine it were a pointer instead of a reference. You could then see `*y = newY` can still be const, because the pointer itself isn't changed, just the pointee. Likewise, the reference isn't changed (that's impossible), just what its referring to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because you are not changing any variable in `X`. Actually, you are changing `_y` which is an outsider with respect to your class. Don't forget that:

```
y = newY;
```

Is assigning the value of `newY` to the variable pointed by `y`, but not the references them selves. Only on initialization the references are considered.

Comment: +1, this is the answer. Note the equivalency with pointers, perhaps that's easier to wrap your head around, let's say you declare `int *y;`, then `*y = newY` is valid, but `y = &newY` is not.

Comment: thanks. I think what I really wanted is a pointer as a member.

Comment: Of course, y could be made to refer to a class member, and then it would be modifying the state of the class. It just so happens that in this example it doesn't.

Comment: @visitor: My first thought too. But that would be evil.

Answer (score 8):

The situation is similar to pointer members. In a const member function, the const applies to the pointer itself, not the pointee.

It's the difference between:

```
X* const //this is how the const applies: you can modify the pointee
const X*
```

Except `X& const` isn't valid syntax, since the reference can't be made to refer to another object in the first place (they are implicitly always const). In conclusion: const on methods has no effect on member references.

Answer (score 2):

As additional information for the accepted answer, I want to say, in fact one can 
change variables in X.

> Because you are not changing any variable in X.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Bar {
public:
    void funcA() const {
        c++;
    }

    int b = 3;
    int &c = b;
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    b.funcA();
    cout << b.b << endl;  //4
}
```

So the main idea for this problem is:

> It modifies what the member refers to, it does not modify the member.

This also applies for pointer members.

See here [Why can reference members be modified by const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436836/why-can-reference-members-be-modified-by-const-member-functions)