# Design reasons for the behavior of reference members of classes passed by const reference

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose to have the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A{
  int y;
  int& x;
  A():y(0),x(y){}
};



void f(int& x){
  x++;
}

void g(const A& a){
  f(a.x);
  //f(a.y);
}


int main(){
  A a;
  g(a);
  std::cout<<a.y<<std::endl;

}
```

inside g()
calling f() on y is not allowed because a is passed with the const modifier
however, the value of y can be modified inside g() by calling f on x;

With pointers, a similar things can be obtained very similarly

```
struct B{
  int* x;  
}
```

and

```
g(const B&){
   *x++;
}
```

is allowed. This is perfectly clear: We have a const pointer to non-const int.
But in the previous reference example, if references ARE the object, why do in this case they behave as pointers? What are the design policies under this behavior?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431596/modifying-reference-member-from-const-member-function-in-c?rq=1 is the same issue; it may not go far enough into the motivation though.

Comment: @ecatmur : Thank you, this is exactly the same, I will link it, but, as you state, the reply does not go much further than "because it is like with pointers"

Comment: References **aren't** the object, they are a **reference** to an object.

Comment: @ereOn I agree,but see for instance  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c

Comment: @FabioDallaLibera: I read it. Note that the "is" in the accepted answer is *emphased*, indicating that care is required when interpreting this sentence. It is sometimes acceptable to see a reference as being the object in some particular cases as it simplifies the logic. However, it is important to remember that references are still a different beast *most of the time*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual language in the standard is

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 8.3.2 References [dcl.ref]
>
> 1 - [...]
>   [ Note: A reference can be thought of as a name of an object. —end note ]

So if a reference is a *name* of an object, not an object itself, then it makes sense that causing the enclosing structure to be `const` makes the name `const` (which is meaningless, as references can't be rebound), but not the object itself.

We also see

> 6 - 
>   If a typedef, a type template-parameter, or a decltype-speciﬁer denotes a type TR
>   that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* TR” creates the type “lvalue reference to T” [...]

Since member access on a *cv* object creates a *cv* lvalue, the same applies and the *cv* qualification is extinguished.

Comment: Thank you. And I think @Useless comment adds an important thing here: making a reference itself const isn't very useful: since they're non-reseatable, they can't be mutated like pointers in any case.

Comment: Thank you! Here is point 6 in action:



typedef int& C;

template<typename X> struct V{
  const X& x;
  V(X& px):x(px){}
};

int main(){ 
  int x;
  C c(x);
  V<C> v(c);
  v.x=3;
}

Answer (score 4):

> if references ARE the object

references are *not* objects though - they're references to objects.

You're right that making a reference itself const isn't very useful: since they're non-reseatable, they can't be mutated like pointers in any case.

In fact, it might be more helpful to think of a reference as a const pointer (not a pointer-to-const!) with special syntax.

Note that if you *want* an indirection which does propogate constness from the referee to the referent (ie, to prevent the `f(a.x)` call here), you can write a smart pointer-style thing to do it.

---

Concrete example

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int *p;
    int &r;

    A() : x(0), p(&x), r(x) {}
};
```

Now in `A a`:

- `a.x` is a mutable int
- `a.p` is a mutable pointer (so we can reseat it) to a mutable int (we can change the value of the integer it points to)
- and `a.r` is a reference to a mutable int

  - note that since we can't mutate (reseat) references anyway, it doesn't mean anything for the reference itself to be either const or mutable

... but in `const A b`:

- `b.x` is a constant integer
- `b.p` is a constant pointer (so we can't reseat it) to a mutable int
- `b.r` is a reference to a mutable int

  - note how the constness is applied to the member of A (the pointer or reference) and does *not* propogate through to the referent.

Comment: Thank you. I like your answer. Now a further step.
struct B{
  int* x;
}

Now, a const B is the same as a B with a int*  const;
However with 
struct C{
  int& x;
}
x is not a const int&. How would you call it?

Comment: Nope, a `const B` has a const member x, which is to say `int * const B::x`. The member is a pointer, so the const member is a const pointer _not a pointer-to-const_. So, you can still modify whatever `x` points to, but you can't modify `x` (by re-seating it).

Comment: Thank you. I marked @ecatmur response for reporting standard's excerpts, but I could mark your answer as accpted answer as well. I'll add up points

Answer (score 0):

In C++ references are usually implemented by pointers.  (I think that the `sizeof` a reference and pointer are the same).

Indeed I usually think of references as pointers, but with different syntax.

Comment: "I think that the sizeof a reference and pointer are the same" Nope

Comment: I do too, although many people are strongly against it, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you saying that they are never the same or just sometimes?

Comment: @quamrana `sizeof(T&)` is identically the same as `sizeof(T)`. it has no relationship to the size of a pointer. the size of memory used for a reference may be 0 or the same as for `T*`, or something else, at the compiler's discretion, and is not available via `sizeof` (to check it you can place a reference in a `struct`, say).