# A reference data-member changing another data member inside a const function

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I apologize if this question has already been asked, but I could not find the same question.
Please redirect me to the relevant question.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class ABC
{
    int a;
    int &ref;
public:    
    ABC(int arg = 0):a(arg), ref(a){}
    void mutate_func(int arg) const {
        ref = arg;
    }
    void print_val() {
        cout << endl << &a << "\t" << &ref;
        cout << endl << a << "\t" << ref;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ABC abc_obj(5);
    cout << sizeof(abc_obj);

    abc_obj.print_val();
    abc_obj.mutate_func(10);
    abc_obj.print_val();
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to modify a data-member of a class inside a const member function through a reference variable which is part of the same class only.

I have two questions -

1. Why it is not throwing compilation error.
2. I am printing address of both variables and as expected both are showing same address, but still sizeof() for the instance is showing size as 8 bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying reference member from const member function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431596/modifying-reference-member-from-const-member-function-in-c)

Comment: @Andrey This is a bit different since the value being referred to is also part of the same object.

Comment: Compiler couldn't know that when compiling `mutate_func`

Comment: @Andrey Is this the same reason why object size is 8 bytes ??

Comment: Yes. You could expect the compiler is so clever to optimize `ref` away, but it is not the case. See the answer of Johannes Schaub.

Answer (score 2):

1. The compiler cannot track reference destinations completely at compile time.
2. Because somewhere it needs to be stored where a reference refers to.

This is a class making it very easy to trigger undefined behavior. Just create a const object of it and call the const member function.

C++ supports the `mutable` keyword for a supported mechanism of changing the bits of an object in a const member function.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, this was useful. I am aware of mutable keyword. But I was wondering isn't using reference to change the datamember inside const function kind of hacking??? isn't there some runtime check in place ??

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the sizeof and address part.

A reference can be seen like a pointer with a lighter syntax so it needs storage space equivalent to a pointer (4 bytes here).

A reference is modified only during its initialization `ref(a)`. After its initialization, any operation on the reference is performed on the referenced value, so `&ref` gives the address of the referenced value and not the reference itself. So `&a == &ref` makes perfect sense.

Comment: so what happens to the original memory of reference ?? isn't this kind of memory leak problem encountered with pointers ??

Comment: Memory leaks appear only when you allocate data and not delete it later (using `new` and `delete` for example). If you're only pointing data there are no leaks possible. A reference references some data there's no allocation here. The space used by the reference contains the location of referenced data and nothing else.