# Modifying const object through pointer obtained during construction

Tags: c++, constants

I just discovered how easy it is to modify const objects without any `const_cast` black magic. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test(int v)
        :m_val{ v },
        m_ptr{ &m_val }
    {}

    int get() const { return m_val; }
    void set(int v) const { *m_ptr = v; }

private:
    int m_val;
    int* m_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    const Test t{ 10 };

    std::cout << t.get() << '\n';
    t.set(0);
    std::cout << t.get() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Recent versions of Clang, GCC, and MSVC don't show any warning and produce expected output:

> 10 0

Is this well defined behavior according to the current standard? If it's undefined what if `m_val` was of type `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(int), alignof(int)>` and constructor `new`'ed `int` in it? I believe it's pretty common case when it comes to small buffer optimizations.

**Edit**

Thanks, it seems that it's just another way to shoot yourself in a foot. 
What's troubling it seems that this:

```
struct Test2 {
    int i;
    void operator()() { ++i; }
};

const std::function<void()> f{ Test2{ 10 } };
f();
```

is also undefined behavior when implementation chooses to store the `Test2` object inside `f` (and that's the case in libc++ and in Visual Studio)

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431596/modifying-reference-member-from-const-member-function-in-c

Comment: I think it is UB that `m_val` is modified.

Comment: *"7.1.5.1/4:

Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior."*

Comment: And with `constexpr`, compilers found the error: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1bcd6da0fdb81bb). :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`const` enforces "bitwise constness", but what you usually want is "logical constness".

In the case of an object that contains a pointer, this means that a const member function can't modify the pointer itself, but can modify what the pointer refers to. In other words, these examples are well formed, but have undefined behavior.

To get logical constness, you 1) use `mutable` (or sometimes `const_cast`) to allow modification of members that don't affect the object's logical state (e.g., cached values/memoization), and 2) generally have to manually enforce not writing to data through a pointer (but if it's an owning pointer, that ownership should probably be delegated to an object that *only* manages ownership of that data, in which case making it const should normally prevent writing to the data it owns).

As far as the specific detail of having a non-const pointer pointing to data that might itself have been const modified, well, you're basically just getting a (persistent) version of roughly the same thing that `const_cast` is typically used to do: get non-const access to data to which you'd otherwise only have a `const` pointer. It's up to you to ensure that you only use this in ways that doesn't cause a problem (but just having and/or writing through that pointer doesn't, in itself, necessarily lead to a problem).

In other words, what we have here are two separate pointers to some data. `this` lets you access an object's data. In a `const` member function, you can only read (not) write data via `this`, unless (as noted above) it's marked `mutable`. In this case, you're saving a second pointer to the same data. Since there's nothing to mark that as a pointer to `const`, it's not, so you get non-const access to the data it points at.

Comment: Note that `m_val` (of const instance `t`) is modified.

Comment: That's why we need the [`propagate_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)

Comment: So, is the example in the question legal or not?

Comment: @MikeMB: Both examples are well formed by have undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thats my expectation too, but I'm missing that clear cut statement in your answer. Maybe I'm reading the question wrong, but as far as I can tell, the central question was never "Why does it compile?", but rather "is this well defined behavior according to the current standard?" (the last is a direct quote from the question)

Comment: @MikeMB: I guess from my perspective, the interesting question was mostly: "how should I write code that might have to deal with a situation like this", but I've added a clear statement for those who care about it.

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out in comments: you are modifying object the `m_ptr` points to. This "pointed to" object is not a part of `class Test` (as far as compiler sees it). That's why compiler allows you to do so.

Having said that, I believe that it will be undefined behaviour. That's because `m_ptr` actually points to another member variable (`m_val`) of object `const Test t`! Compilers are allowed to optimize arggresively and they might rely on constness to do so.

The only exception is then you use `mutable` keyword, but it's another story.

Comment: Note that `m_val` (of const instance `t`) is modified.

Comment: Yes, I just edited my answer to reflect that. Thank's for pointing that out :) .

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are two types of constness in *C++*: physical constness and logical constness.

As for the physical constness everything is perfectly valid in the considered piece of code because `set()` modifies a value which is pointed by `m_ptr` and not the pointer itself which is a part of the class.

Logical constness is violated here. But there many ways in *C++* to violate logical constness because this type of constness relies much on the particular class design.

In the example above program leads to UB because it tries to change a const object.

From the n4296, 7.1.6.1 *The cv-qualifiers*:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified,
>   any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results
>   in undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver seems that compiler doesn't know about it :)

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behavior.  Not all `const` declared types are indeed constants, so it's not always undefined behavior to modify something declared that way.  You could have a reference to a const type that refers to a non-const non-const value, cast away constness and modify the value without invoking undefined behavior.  In this case though the original definition is `const` so you must assume it's a constant.

Modification of any constant is undefined behavior and yes, there's numerous ways to "accidentally" do so.  In the aligned_storage version then yes, it's undefined behavior to modify that *constant* data by using placement new to modify it.

Comment: placement-new creates a new object, it does not modify existing objects. (But there is a rule that using placement-new where there is/was a `const` object causes undefined behaviour)