# Can the value of element inside the struct that is passed by as const reference be modified?

Tags: c++, struct

In the following function, n is a const reference to the actual parameter, and it is not legal to change its value.

```
void DoWork(const int &n);
```

How about a const reference of struct? Can we change 'index' inside 'Test'? The following code will print 100. Isn't that 'Test' unchangeable?

```
struct Test {
    int& index ;
};

void doSth(const Test& test) {
    test.index = 100;
};

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    Test test = {
      .index = a,
    };
    doSth(test);
    std::cout << test.index;
}
```

How should I understand this?

I tried running the code and it print 100, so apparent 'index' can be modified though we declare 'test' as const reference.

Comment: Right.  You can't change `test` to refer to another struct, but you can change the structure `test` refers to.

Comment: I suppose that technically, the following is not a duplicate because it covers a `const` member function, but that does follow the same semantics as passing a parameter by `const` reference: [Modifying reference member from const member function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2431596)

Comment: @TimRoberts *"you can change the structure `test` refers to..."* That seems wrong. For example, if you have a non-reference member, the program won't compile.

Comment: @JaMiT This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431769/12002570) in the dupe explains what is happenig here as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we change 'index' inside 'Test'?

No you can't.

However, you might be surprised to learn that assigning something to this `index` does not change it in any way. The reference itself remains completely unchanged. It's still a reference to some `int` value, somewhere. And the assignment modifies that `int` value, somewhere. It does not modify the reference itself. It still references the same `int` value that it referenced before the assignment.

> Isn't that 'Test' unchangeable?

Correct. And that assignment does not change it in any way. It changes whatever that reference is referencing.

Note that you cannot "change 'index' inside 'Test'" even if your reference to the `Test` is not `const`:

```
void doSth(Test& test) {
```

Even without a `const` here there's nothing that can be done to change the reference.

This is because, in C++, once a reference exists, it cannot be changed. It will remain a reference in perpetuity:

```
int& index ;
```

Once this is constructed you cannot do anything to change this `index`. Assigning anything to it merely changes what this references. It does not change the reference itself.

In C++ all references themselves are logically `const`.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't that 'Test' unchangeable?

In your example, it **IS** "unchangeable". `index` itself is not being modified, it is the underlying `int` value which is being modified.

For examples sake - It can be noted that the code will not compile if `index` was not a reference. i.e.

```
struct Test {
    int index ;
};
```

In such a case, this is what can be understood as attempting to modify an immutable object, with the compiler preventing you from doing so.

Comment: This is correct. If 'index' is not reference, the code will not compile.

Comment: If the constness is applying to the reference, the reference should be `const int&` which sitll shouldn't be able to modify the underlying `int`.